# How to convert String Values to Integer Array List - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, integer

I want to input 3 data From 3 EditText fields and it will want to display as a  Bar-Chart.

Here is my code section. Give me a solution for these errors..

I tried to get this Bar Chart using this code. But it is not working. i Comment The //ERROR POINT

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getfromdb);

    final String[] mMonth = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        };

    final EditText t1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final EditText t2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final EditText t3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    Button btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);  

    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
    int x3 = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString());

     btnChart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openChart();

            } 
              private void openChart() {

                    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
                    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
                    int x3 = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString());

                int[] x = { 0,1,2 };
                int [] income = {x1 ,x2, x3};    //ERROR POINT


                XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Pulse Rate");                 
                XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("");

                for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){            
                    incomeSeries.add(i,income[i]);

                }

                XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
                dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);       


                XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
                incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


                XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 80, 80));
                expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);        


                XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
                multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
                multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Pulse Chart");
                multiRenderer.setXTitle("Pulse rate");
                multiRenderer.setYTitle("Days");
                multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);              
                for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
                    multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);          
                }       

                multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
                multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

                Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

}

private void setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I Comment the //ERROR POINT in code segment.
When i give the values this point as a

```
    int [] income = {60 ,40, 50};             //It should Be working
```

Then it Should be Working.. But i want to put these values Using EditText boxes.

Comment: did you get a error?

Comment: Take Integer[] income and try.

Comment: Are you sure u are taking value of t1.getText().toString() after entering it in edittext

Comment: define _"NOT WORKING"_

Comment: I put the whole code.. Now give me a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to this line

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

try to this repalcing

```
    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()).getIntValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, take an Integer array of income -:
**Integer[] income = {x1,x2,x3};**

Than you can use **Arrays.asList(income)**

Comment: tell me how to implement arrays.asList(income)

Comment: You dont need to implement, asList is a Utility method of the Arrays class which is in java.util package.

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText t1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final EditText t2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final EditText t3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

ArrayList<Integer> integersList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integersList.add(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()));
integersList.add(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString()));
integersList.add(Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: This is not working.  i put the the Whole code. Please give me a solution

Comment: Are you sure you are getting values correctly from EditText ? did you tried placing Log to see if values you are getting for x1,x2,x3 are as expected ? your for loop is also using x instead of income array to check the length see if its the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `openChart` method as follows:

```
private void openChart() {
    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
    int x3 = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString());

    int[] income = {x1 ,x2, x3};

}
```

Comment: This is not working. i put the the Whole code. Please give me a solution

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert from Integer to int then you should write code like

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()).getIntValue();
```

then use the int value somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your this code

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());
 int x2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString());
 int x3 = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString());
```

form this

```
                int x1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()).getIntValue();;
                int x2 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString()).getIntValue();;
                int x3 = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString()).getIntValue();;
```